# pip equivalent to "easy_install ."

Tags: python

Simple Question ;)

Is there a way to simply install the package using [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) once you build it.  Using [easy_install](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) I would simply build my [package](http://code.google.com/p/pybugz/) it (`python setup.py build`), then if I was happy do a `easy_install .` and this would dump the resulting egg into the right place.  How do I do this using pip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip install -e .` will install from a local source like `easy_install .` would.

Most of pip's commands and functionality are designed around installing from source repositories or [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) package listings, or maintaining consistently versioned dependencies though.

If you are going through the steps of building the package yourself, are you sure you don't want to `python setup.py install` manually after you are satisfied with the build?

Comment: Good point - I guess the reason would be to utilize the freeze functionality.  I'm just getting started with pip.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work the way I was thinking...  Bummer.  But then again neither did pip.   So the right answer is simple python setup.py install..  Duh

Comment: @rh0dium What were you expecting?

Comment: Back then (09') pip didn't behave this way!